# How to install a conda environment with Spyder and Python 2.7?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

SOmething as simple as:

```
conda create -n py2 python=2.7
```

and then in that environment

```
conda install spyder=3
```

fails to solve for the environment. Although the only things here are python=2.7 basics and spyder=3, which on their own website specifies requires python 2.7
https://www.psych.mcgill.ca/labs/mogillab/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/doc/installation.html#requirements

Why does this fail, and how can one get something that basic to work?

New attempts: (Last one are specific versions that I know work together, as I have them on my main system wide install).

```
conda create -n py2 python=2.7 spyder                    --> Fails to solve env

conda create -n py2 python=2.7 spyder -c free            --> installs spyder4

conda create -n py2 python=2.7 spyder=3 -c free          --> AttributeError on launch

conda create -n py2 python=2.7.17 spyder=3.2.3 -c free   --> AttributeError on launch
```

All fail. If I don't specify spyder=3, conda installs spyder=4, which is a no-go as those versions of python and spyder do not work together (why doesn;t conda know this when checking for compatibility?). When specifying spyder=3, environment fails to solve except when using `channel free`, as kindly suggested in the comments. But this method also fails when launching Spyder, throwing AttributeErrors.

Comment: Try `conda create -n py2 python=2.7 spyder`. You might need to use a different channel, like `free`.

Comment: @AMC that works but it installs spyder 4, which then fails to launch because of the version incompatibility between python2 and spyder 4. Why conda fails to identify that incompatibility is also confusing to me.  If I establish spyder=3 in the install the environment fails to create. Do you have this issue as well? It is a really quick test, I am very curious if its a general issue

Comment: If I specify the channel free, it does install spyder 3.x but fails to launch with errors. Different errors for every Spyder 3 version I;ve tried, all related to some AttributeError on launch...

Answer (score 5):

I hit some Qt issues when launching, that seem to resolve with fixing `qtawesome` to an older version. Here's the final spec that works for me (**osx-64**):

```bash
conda create -n py2 --override-channels -c conda-forge python=2.7 spyder=3.3 qtawesome=0.7
```

or as a YAML

**py2.yaml**

```yaml
name: py2
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=2.7
  - spyder=3.3
  - qtawesome=0.7
```

Comment: Spot on. Can I ask you please how did you manage to find that solution? Between all possible dependencies and versions, and with no error message pointing to that one... ?

Comment: Also for some reason when I created that environment, conda added the systems root path into sys.path. So yes, spyder runs, but its not spyder from that environment, but rather the spyder of my system-wide install...

Comment: @hirschme trial and error. First, I assumed Conda Forge channel had all requisite packages (they are designed for that and were building Spyder for Python 2 pre-sunset). Second, I just did `spyder=3` and `python=2.7` at first, but saw it was picking an unnecessarily old one, so I forced `spyder=3.3`. Next, there were Python errors in the `qtawesome` code and figured there wasn't a good upper bound constraint, so just picked the latest version that was at least pre-2020 (Python 2 sunset), assuming it must have worked then, hence the `qtawesome=0.7`.

Comment: As for `sys.path`, make sure `PYTHONPATH` is empty. Conda is designed with the assumption that environments are isolated; leaky environments have unpredictable behavior. Also, may need to delete any Python packages that were installed with the `--user` flag; these again leak into environments and can have unexpected consequences.

Comment: @hirschme May also be worth mentioning that `mamba` makes the trial and error significantly faster. But I figured you were mostly interested in the navigationally heuristics, rather than the boat I used.